# delete prestashop import csv files

Tags: prestashop

Simple question: How can I delete the PrestShop import CSV files from the system?
I have tried with FTP as well, I could not locate the files.

It show many rows in the dropdown in the import window and I dont know enymore which is the newest of the same named file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your files will be located in `admin/import/*` (admin here is your backoffice directory, that used to be renamed in the older versions) directory, and deleting through FTP is the best way you can do this. I am not sure about the latest version of Presta, but the major one before it didn't have deletion of these files anywhere in GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The newest file will be the uppermost when choosing in backoffice.  The admin/import is where you'll find your csv files to delete all at once rather than one at a time in your back office.  Lastly, your folder name may not be called,"admin" but will be called whatever you or for example,  your autoinstaller of prestashop named it when you installed prestashop. It will be the same name that you use to login to your back office of prestashop (the name before the "@yoururl.com",".org", etc.